# How to log recovery by redelivery in Apache-Camel error handler?

Tags: error-handling, apache-camel

How can I find when a ***Camel route redelivery error handler successfully recovered one error case***.

I would like to be able to ***get metrics around successful redelivery*** by a camel error handler retry.

I would like to know how many message exchange instances that happened to have a network error performing file transfer where successful recovered after retry.